# Comparison of decimal numbers in bash

Tags: bash, arithmetic, floating-point

My search this morning was about how could I compare two decimal numbers in bash, and I came to this answser: [How to compare to floating point number in a shell script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/24721/9491). This one, however, doesn't include [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23160798/756589):

```
$ [[ ((3.56 < 2.90)) ]]; echo $?
1
$ [[ ((3.56 < 4.90)) ]]; echo $?
0
```

Considering that answer has been downvoted, and it looks some kind of unusual bashism, is this arithmetic evaluation trustworthy for accuracy?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`bash` does not understand floating point numbers.
Quoting `bash` manual page, section *ARITHMETIC EVALUATION*:

> Evaluation is done in fixed-width integers […].

So `((3 < 4))` or `((3 < 2))` are actually correct arithmetic expressions. You can type the following:

```
$ echo "$((3 < 4)) -- $((3 < 2))"
```

> output: `1 -- 0`

But `$ echo $((3.3 < 3.6))` will return a syntax error message. In your example, you are actually comparing strings. Hence some example:

```
$ [[ ((3.56 < 04.90)) ]]; echo $?
```

> output: `1`

Comment: Both answers are awesome, but I'm choosing yours because of the example, which made me realize what could go wrong :)

Answer (score 13):

Inside `[[...]]` `<` is for string comparison.

So `[[ 3.56 < 2.90 ]]` or `[[ (3.56 < 2.90) ]]` or `[[ ((3.56 < 2.90)) ]]` or `[[ (((3.56 < 2.90))) ]]`... is just comparing the `3.56` string with the `2.90` string lexically (and lexically, `3` is greater than `10` for instance).

For integer comparison, it's `[[ 3 -lt 2 ]]` or `(( 3 < 2 ))`. If you want floating point comparison, you need `ksh93`, `zsh` or `yash` or an external utility like `awk` or `perl`; `bash` can't do it.

You could for instance define a function like:

```
compare() (IFS=" "
  exec awk "BEGIN{if (!($*)) exit(1)}"
)
```

Which you could use for instance like:

```
if compare '1.5*10 < 1e3'; then
  echo less
fi
```

Or even for that matters:

```
if compare '"bar" < "foo"'...
```

to do string comparisons.

Do not pass uncontrolled externally provided data to that `compare` function as it would constitute a command injection vulnerability (the data is interpreted as `awk` code, `awk` can run commands with its `system()` for instance).

Comment: To illustrate the importance of the difference between string vs. numeric comparison, consider that `[[ 11.56 < 2.90 ]]` (and `[[ ((11.56 < 2.90)) ]]` and...) is true, because "1" comes before "2" in ascii sorting order.

Comment: @GordonDavisson, yes, and `[[ 0.1 < 1e-20 ]]` and whether `[[ -2 < 1 ]]` is locale-dependent.

Comment: `[[ 3 -lt 2 ]]` uses conditional expression, and `(( 3 < 2 ))` uses arithmetic expression. When comparing two integers, can these two methods always be used interchangeably? If yes, why does Bash have two methods rather than one?