# leaking memory with shell script and tty

Tags: shell, tty, raspberry-pi, memory-leaks, arduino

I'm running a shell script on a raspberry pi to communicate with a arduino.
Every hour my ram gets used up by about 50 megabytes more.

The script itself just connects to ttyACM0 (the arduino's usb terminal) and then sends a char to it.
The script runs once per minute to check the Temps. Values for the first argument can be: 'a', 'b' or 'T'. 
In the case of 'a' or 'b' it switches on/off a relay.
In the case of 'T' the arduino returns 3 temperature values, which I store.

The script runs fine (I can control the relay and receive values, without the arduinos serial getting restarted). but I'm having issues because of my limited memory.

I don't have any other processes running on the device and already tried a fresh raspbian setup.

Can somebody tell me where and if there are memory leaks in this script and how I can prevent them?

**EDIT: I found the culprit:
the script runs hundreds of 'cat' commands with time, how do I get rid of them?
I already tried killall cat, but this resets my raspberrys serial connection (I want to prohibit that, because it 'restarts' the arduino!)
@mikeserv pointed me towards using head, which automatically quits after reading a defined number of lines, unfortunately that doesn't work either. And I can't seem to get the temperatures written in my output file without a pipe**

```
head -n3 <&3 >>/home/pi/output
```

doesn't work as it's not exiting too and I don't get any output

I could kill all cat's every few minutes to free the mem, but this also resets my tty to arduino (so it reboots and loses the state for the relay)

Edit2: I did not manage to get this working (I tried several possibilities including minicom, screen etc...) but the receiving part is where I have trouble. Sending chars to the arduino works fine though!

```
#!/bin/bash

# READ / WRITE ARDUINO

exec 3<> /dev/ttyACM0

echo "connected, sleep for 1 sec..."
sleep 1

echo "send $1..."

echo "$1" >&3

if [ "$1" = "T" ]
then
        cat <&3 | cat >> /home/pi/output &2>1
else
        echo "nothing to save"
fi

echo "closing.."

exec 3>&-

exit 0
```

Comment: `cat <&3 | cat >> /home/pi/output &2>1` results in backgrounded `cat` commands...

Comment: without the &2>1 it waits forever at this line, what else can I use?

Comment: why not `cat <&3 >>/home/pi/output`? this is also portable - so why not use a shell much less likely to hog resources - maybe `#!/bin/dash`?

Comment: also hangs at the same line... arduino's tty is a bit more complex I guess my script works and I receive my temp values, only those cat processes are my problem.

Comment: what is the first arg - `"$1"` - it looks like this may be a candidate for a `while getopts` loop. But I don't understand how - or why - it receives the args.

Comment: the args (basically 'a', 'b' or 'T') either control a relay, or (in the case of T) receive temperature values from sensors connected to the arduino

Comment: What happens if after you get your T you `cat <&3 | cat >> /dev/null`, i.e., force the buffer into the trash?

Comment: You need to trash the Buffer in the Else too

Comment: Then when is `$1` a `1`? I think I might understand. The `cat </dev/ttyACM0 |cat >file` just hangs reading the tty - it never gets an EOF on `</dev/ttyACM0` because when you close the descriptor you do so in the current shell not in `cat`'s subshell. So you should be using instead `head -n$GUARANTEED_NUMBER_OF_AVAILABLE_LINES` or `sed $LINESq` or something - something that will explicitly quit input.

Comment: @mikeserv See update, although your track is better than mine is.

Comment: @mikeserv thanks for this! i tried it with head and don't even need to put the process in background. The line is now:       head -n3 <&3 | head -n3 >> /home/pi/output
THANKS to everyone! Mike if you answer this I will accept!

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do, but note that `cat >> /home/pi/output &2>1` runs `cat >> /home/pi/output`, and runs the null command with the redirection `2>1` (i.e. standard error redirected to the file called `1`), which creates an empty file called `1`. Did you mean `2>&1`, or `2>&1 &`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you:

```
exec 3<> /dev/ttyACM0
```

... you open a read/write file-descriptor to the usb serial tty on 3 which is automatically inherited by children - such as cloned subshells - and this is why you can read it with `cat <&3` later in your backgrounded pipeline.

The thing is, though, because you background the pipeline - which puts it and all associated subshells in a separate process group - it is not closed for the pipeline processes later when you...

```
exec 3<&-
```

...and close that descriptor for the script's current shell processes. Instead...

```
cat </dev/ttyACM0 | cat >> file &
```

...hangs in the background, reading nothing for as long as there is nothing to read, and keeping an open line on that tty the whole time. This is because `cat` only quits its input on EOF, which, in this case, it never receives.

You can do:

```
cat /dev/tty
```

... at your prompt to approximate that behavior.

What you should be doing is explicitly quitting the input as soon as you have read as much as you need, or else explicitly killing `cat` after same. You might do this like:

```
head -n"$GUARANTEED_NUM_AVAIL_INPUT LINES" <&3 >>file
```

... or with `sed [num]q` or similar. In this way you should avoid having to `|pipe` at all, and likely can omit the `&`backgrounding entirely. Else to kill `cat` you might do:

```
cat <&3 >>file &
sleep 1 && kill "$!"
```

...but probably that is not necessary, as quitting the input is far more simple.

As an aside, it is worth noting that your script is already composed entirely of portable syntax, and so it is probably worth your while to alter the `#!/bin/bash` line and instead invoke a lighter-weight - and likely faster - shell instead. I recommend `dash` for something like this. Have a look [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/148035/52934) if interested in this line of thinking for a q&a on performance comparisons between various shells - to include both `bash` and `dash`.

Comment: This verifies my buffer overflow theory.   +1

Comment: unfortunately its not solved, the head commands sum up too! and I can't seem to get anything written in my output without the pipe :/

Comment: @Gotschi, Well, the pipe is a problem because it will buffer at 4096k when run without job control. Possibly you can use `read` to do what you need - like `{ IFS= read -r line1; IFS= read -r line2; IFS= read -r line3; printf %s\\n "$line1" "$line2" "$line3" } <&3 >>file`, but there is also the usb buffer to consider. Interesting is that it works as is for one device and not for the other. How does it work if you `exec 3</dev/ttyACM0 4>/dev/ttyACM0` and use `echo >&4 "$1"` ... `head -n3 3<&` or else get `head` to open the dev explicitly like `head -n3 /dev/ttyACM0 >> file`?

Comment: @Gotschi - Or does perhaps the arduino need the serial line closed *before* it will send the temps? For example, before you were doing `open tty; cat tty &; close tty` which would allow `cat` to receive *after* you close the tty. Actually, are you using any sort of terminal program here to create the tty in the first place `minicom`, `screen`, anything? Or is this the only open that happens at all?

Comment: Im just using the normal tty (I guess). Im not so sure what I'm doing at all and whats going wrong, but I made this so that the serial port on the arduino does not get restarted every time I query for the temps. Out of the reason that arduino does a restart (and loses the relay state) on a new serial connect. I used screen for initial testing, which just displays 3 lines with numbers as soon as i hit 'T'

Comment: @mikeserv should i just reprogram the arduino to return EOF after the 3 temp variables? will this work?

Comment: @Gotschi - I found [this](http://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/LinuxTTY) - some of that indicates that the arduino *won't* properly duplex the connection. At the top, though, you'll see the `stty` command for properly configuring the tty device - that is, *at the least*, what you should be doing to handle the tty i/o. Please read through that - probably you'll find an answer that you can write and accept yourself. Sorry it took me so long to get back - my car's window seized so I had to fix it, and my glasses broke in the process which also needed fixing, and....

Comment: haha then mucho gracias for the help!! ;) I didn't manage to get it working with changed stty settings, but I solved it by attaching the temp sensors directly to the pi and now don't need to receive anything from the serial anymore. Just send chars to turn on/off the relay. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I can't write you a fix, but I can explain what's happening.

1. You're opening the Port.
2. Your checking/sending values from the temperature sensor.
3. You're closing the port.

Some possibilities:

- The USB Buffer from the Arduino is Filling until you rerun the script, but the buffer is still full from the last run.  You'r inadvertently causing a buffer overflow in your Comm Port, as the amounts of previous runs pile up in the buffer.
- The same issue is occurring in the Raspberry Pi, as the buffer fills in the same way from the other direction.

---

You need to find a way to clear the buffer on both sides so that the gate opens, sends 3, and closes, opens, sends 3, and closes etc. Subshelling, as Yeti suggests is one way.  I'm sure there are other, such as closing and reopening the buffer but not killing the CommPort.  Since I'm no expert on Comm Drivers, I can only offer a theory.

**Update**

```
If [ "$1" = "T" ]
then
        cat <&3 | cat >> /home/pi/output &2>1
        cat <&3 | cat >> /dev/null
else
        echo "nothing to save"
        cat <&3 | cat >> /dev/null
fi
```

Comment: thank you for this information! but my problem belongs more to the pi as the arduino shows no signs of trouble.

Comment: See my comment in your OP...

Comment: although your update seemed promising, I had no success :/ the cat processes were still not quitting. using head -n3 works - thanks to both of you!

Comment: When all else Fails count the characters in the buffer... oldest trick in the book :)  Lost another checkmark to mikeserv lol

Comment: @eyoung100 - you did get a mikeserv upvote, if it matters. Still, didn't know you'd lost one to me before? I don't often get accepted answers.

Comment: @mikeserv Neither do I but I love the challenge :)