# Execute only if it is a bash function

Tags: bash, function

I'm looking for something similar to Bash's built-in `command` that will only run something if it is a function. So currently I have an insecure way of doing:

```
# Go through arguments in order
for i in $*; do
    if [ -z `which $i` ]; then
        # Run function
        $i && echo -n ' '
    fi
done
```

This if statement doesn't work properly. Anyway, even if I could check if it's a command and not a function, I can't run explicitly run a function, which is bad because if anyone has any programs in $PATH that are the same name as my function, they will be run. If I nullify PATH or set it to anything else, anyone could still use $i to run a program explicit, so that's also not a solution.

Any way I can "secure" my shell script?

Comment: This looks like a really poor way to work around just having proper argument parsing..

Comment: Right, so instead of functions, can I use something like e.g `xargs` to run certain bash functions? I dunno, I feel pretty limited with bash compared to something like Python, Perl or even C where I know if I run the name of a function from an argument, it's not going to run anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `bash`, you can do something like this:

```
for f do
  if declare -F -- "$f" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    : "$f" is a function, do something with it
  fi
done
```

`declare -F -- "$f" >/dev/null 2>&1` will return success code if `$f` is a bash function, output nothing.

You might also want to disable some special builtin commands when `bash` run in POSIX mode by adding `builtin enable -n -- "$f"`.

Comment: This is really supposed to work? `for f do`? Shouldn't that be `for f in <something> do` instead? I'm wonder if a certain boolean condition could actually turn this into an infinite loop...

Comment: @syntaxerror: `for f do` is shorthand and POSIX way of `for f in "$@"; do`.

Comment: Oh thanks, didn't know that. I'm not going to use it though; the latter variant you quoted will increase readability by at least 25 percent (IMHO), since the `$@` will even be understood by `bash` programmers who only know the more basic syntax.

Comment: one note. you should explicitly quote `$f` in `eval` to prevent an alias expansion in `Posix`-mode (or with `shopt -s expand_aliases`). See [example](https://gist.github.com/evverx/896f76c27cb8211c0234)

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for this. I had to use `-F` instead of `+F` though, but it worked! Since I know that all functions run before commands do, I shouldn't have to worry about that so much. Although it seems like you guys are implying that aliases run even before functions do. Is that true? @EvgenyVereshchagin Should I run `eval "$f"` instead of `$f`, is that what you're saying?

Comment: You can run `$f`. It's ok. But if you use `$f` inside `eval` you should quote it: `eval "'$f'"`. See [Shell Operation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Operation)

Comment: Not sure what you mean. `declare +X var` removes the X attribute to the variable. For `F`, it doesn't make sense. With my version of bash (4.3.11), it doesn't work at all, it returns true for everything that is a valid variable name, and false for functions that don't have a valid variable name (like `:`).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: My mis-understand from manpage, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: There is another edge case in `Posix`-mode: a function with the same name as the [special builtin](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Special-Builtins). See [example](https://gist.github.com/evverx/4fee16ad50e03e169af6#file-quoting-bash)

Comment: @EvgenyVereshchagin: Nice catch! Updated my answer.

Comment: You'd rather prefer the `type -t` builtin, as in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/217292/execute-only-if-it-is-a-bash-function/329230#329230

Answer (score 3):

The formal way Bash provides to do it is using the `type` builtin as of `type -t`:

```bsh
function fun() {
  : foo bar
}

if [ function = $(type -t fun) ]; then
  echo fun is a function.
fi
```

If you are suspicious about the function name from your parameter list, just double-quote it: `$(type -t "$arg")`

Answer (score 1):

While you're probably well set in a `bash` shell, to do similar portably you might employ something like the following...

```sh
eval "  for c in $(unalias -a
        for c do case ${c#function}  in
                (*[!_[:alnum:]]*) ;; (?*)
                PATH=   command -v "$c" >&2 &&
                PATH=   command -V "$c"     &&
                        printf '\n'"'$c'"'\\\0'
        esac 2>/dev/null; done  |
        tr  '\t\n\0' '  \n'     |
        sed -ne's/.* function .* / /p')"'
;do     "$c"; printf %02s
done'
```

It works in stages:

1. First weed out all args which contain any characters that might disqualify them as shell names in the first place.
2. If the current arg is a valid name *and* a valid shell builtin or function print its name and type to stdout. Because of the way shell's can vary their output for `command -V` its output cannot be counted upon to be a single line. So follow the output with our verified name and and a null-byte.
3. `tr`anslate all newlines and tabs to spaces, and all null-bytes to newlines.
4. with `sed`, `s///`ubstitute away all of any line up the last space character thereon and print the results if the line also matches the string *`function`*.
5. All of `sed`'s output is rounded up as iterators for the outer `for` loop and each of these is executed in turn, and after each is executed `printf` writes out two spaces.

Comment: Try this [code](https://gist.github.com/evverx/0211232ae2620ad9326c#file-func_detection-sh). There are three functions in the script, but `dash script foo bar cd` detects only `bar` function.

Comment: @EvgenyVereshchagin - yeah, that was the point - to avoid aliases and builtins.  If the opposite behavior is desired, then for aliases i can just unconditionally `unalias` *(and add a quote to `echo "$c"`)*, and for builtins i can just test for altered output. The whole thing can be done simply like `case $(command -V -- "$c") in (*"$c"*function*|*function*"$c"*)...` but it requires a subshell every test.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. `declare -F`-bashism detects everything. +1 for magical loop body:)

Comment: @EvgenyVereshchagin - you know what, I thought about it, and you had a pretty good point. Try it again.

Comment: wow! works fine in `dash`. There is an edge case in `bash`: function with the same name as the [special builtin](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Special-Builtins) in `Posix`-mode. Try this [code](https://gist.github.com/evverx/ba2b039f75da82e082d4#file-func_detection-bash). `bash script foo bar cd set` detects all functions but run `set` builtin.

Comment: @EvgenyVereshchagin - can you just tell me what happens? What happens? And a shell *should not* be able to name a function named `set` - what kind of crazy stuff is that? I swear, `bash` is *the worst* shell.

Comment: `Bash` is not so bad:) `bash --posix script foo bar cd set` fails with `script: line 10: set': is a special builtin`. but in normal mode you can define a `set` function. `builtin set -o posix`  force `Posix`-mode and special builtins are found before shell functions during command lookup.

Comment: @EvgenyVereshchagin - Oh. Well then it just does the right thing and refuses to define a function named `set()`. That has nothing to do with my code. Line 10 is the `set(){ ... }` line. And yes, `bash` is the worst - it is the slowest, buggiest shell I've ever used.  Here are some [tests](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/148035/52934).