# Bash if statement help variable like dl=40.00; $dl < 500

Tags: bash

```
downloadspeed=800.00
dl="$downloadspeed/1" | bc
if [ $((dl)) -lt 500 ]
then
    echo "slow - send slow message"
else
    echo "fast - no issue"
fi
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried many variations to test the $downloadspeed and this is where I left off. It seems no matter how I test it all is treating my variable as a string. $downloadspeed < 500, $dl < 500, "$dl" < 500, etc. tried so many variations.

Comment: Try your script in https://www.shellcheck.net/ and see if it helps

Comment: Also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40786/how-to-do-integer-float-calculations-in-bash-or-other-languages-frameworks and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24721/how-to-compare-to-floating-point-number-in-a-shell-script

Comment: @Quasímodo great resource for bash checks, thanks.

Comment: @ikkachu good resource also, gave some different examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing wrong is your assignment to `dl`:

```
dl="$downloadspeed/1" | bc
```

This means "set the variable `$dl` to the *string* `800.00/1`, and then pass the output *of the variable assignment* to `bc`". Since the assignment has no output, the result is just setting `dl` to `800.00`.

BUT, and this is important, pipelines run in their own subshell and any variables set in that subshell won't be available to the parent shell. This means that even if this assignment were actually doing what you wanted it to do, `dl` would still only be set while that pipeline is running and would be unset in the script itself.

Then, you run this:

```
if [ $((dl)) -lt 500 ]
```

This means "if the result of executing the contents of the `$dl` variable as an arithmetic expression command are less than 500. To do this, you need to set the value of `dl` to a valid arithmetic expression. For example:

```
800/1
```

But what you have is an empty variable since, as mentioned above, the `$dl` only had a value in the subshell running the pipe.

In any case, this is all really needlessly complicated. Why not do this instead:

```
#!/bin/sh

downloadspeed=800.00
value=$(printf '%s\n' "$downloadspeed"/1 | bc)
if [ $value -lt 500 ]
then
    echo "slow - send slow message"
else
    echo "fast - no issue"
fi
```

---

Next time, to debug such issues, you can use `set -x`. Add it to the start of your script:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -x
downloadspeed=800.00
dl="$downloadspeed/1" | bc
if [ $((dl)) -lt 500 ]
then
    echo "slow - send slow message"
else
    echo "fast - no issue"
fi
```

if you now run your script, you will see exactly what commands are being executed:

```
$ foo.sh
+ downloadspeed=800.00
+ dl=800.00/1
+ bc
+ '[' 0 -lt 500 ']'
+ echo 'slow - send slow message'
slow - send slow message
```

As you can see, because `$dl` is empty but is used inside an arithmetic expression (`$(( ))`), that is evaluated to 0, and you're actually running `[ 0 -lt 500 ]`, which is always true.

Comment: Excellent, $(printf '%s\n' "$downloadspeed"/1 | bc) was the magic sauce. I am fairly new at some of these scripting syntax in bash. Thanks for showing me how to get that output.

Comment: "the result is just setting dl to 800.00" ...in the subshell started for the pipeline, so `dl` is still unset in the main shell, and the arithmetic expression resolves it as zero...

Comment: @ilkkachu oh damn, yes of course. I had completely missed that, thanks! Answer edited.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a shell with floating point arithmetic support like zsh (you're already writing zsh syntax by not quoting your `$((dl))`) instead of bash and do:

```
downloadspeed=800.00
if ((downloadspeed < 500))
then
    echo "slow - send slow message"
else
    echo "fast - no issue"
fi
```

With `bash` or POSIX `sh` syntax which don't support floating point arithmetics, you could call `awk` to do the comparison:

```
compare() { # args: <number> <op> <number>
  POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 awk -- "
    BEGIN {exit(!((0+ARGV[1]) $2 (0+ARGV[2])))}" "$1" "$3"
}

if compare "$downloadspeed" '<' 500
then
    echo "slow - send slow message"
else
    echo "fast - no issue"
fi
```

The `POSIXLY_CORRECT=1` helps in case your `awk` is the GNU implementation to make it recognise more forms of numbers (like `infinity`, `0x10`, `0x1p4`... YMMV with other implementations). The `--` helps with older versions of busybox `awk` which would otherwise treat negative numbers as options. The `0+` is to force a numeric comparison in things like `compare '8 apples' '<' '10 bananas'` (where the trailing text is ignored) instead of resorting to string comparison in those cases.