# Floating point comparison in shell

Tags: shell-script, shell, bc, floating-point

I am comparing the floating point values in shell script based on this [reference](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/24728/452142). Following is the script contents

```
num1=50.960
num2=6.65E+07
echo "${num1} < ${num2}" | bc
```

When I ran the script the output is '0'. But according to the comparison it should be '1'. I need inputs on why the comparison is not working as expected ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `bc` utility does not understand `6.65E+07` as the number you want it to be.

On OpenBSD, the `E` here is hexadecimal, so `6.65E` is 6.664 (6.65 + 0.014), and then `+07` will add 7 to that, yielding 13.664, and that is clearly less than 50.960.  On GNU systems, `6.65E` is `6.659` which is also not what you want.

Instead, you want `num2` to be the string `6.65*10^7` or `66500000`.

```
$ num1=50.960; num2='6.65*10^7'; printf '%s < %s\n' "$num1" "$num2" | bc
1
```

Comment: FWIW, GNU `bc` treats `6.65E` as `6.659`. If it treated `6.65E` as a hex number, I'd expect it to yield 6.39794921875 (see `printf '%.15g\n' 0x6.65E`)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Ah, so this is on OpenBSD. I should mention that.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas What I meant was that it seems to do an addition of 14 scaled to the position of the `E` in the number somehow. In any case, it's not doing what the user want it to.

Comment: @Kusalananda, On stackoverflow, it's suggested to use "E" for scientific notation. Are those inputs wrong ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/31087503/8994194

Comment: @Raja Yes, that is wrong. I don't know if that was correct advice at some point, but it's not correct today.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use num2 as is you could use awk:

```
awk -v num1="$num1" -v num2="$num2" 'BEGIN{exit num1<=num2}'
```

This will compare the two numbers and exit 1 if num1 is less than num2 or exit 0 otherwise.

Note: this will exit 1 if num1 and num2 are equal which is the same behavior you would see from bc in that case, if you want it to exit 0 in that case you will need to use `<` instead of `<=`.

Comment: Or `exit num1 >= num2`?

Comment: That seems the opposite of what is needed but is a better way to do it thanks

Comment: Yeah, I put may brain in backwards this morning...

Comment: I'd do `awk -- 'BEGIN{exit !(ARGV[1] < ARGV[2])}' "$num1" "$num2"` (so you can also use it as string comparison when operands are not numbers and remember `-v` mangles strings with backslashes).

Comment: Or `compare() { awk -- "BEGIN{exit !(ARGV[1] $2 ARGV[2])}" "$1" "$3"; }` and then `compare "$num1" '<' "$num2"` for instance.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the `dc` utility by first converting the engineering notation to floating point.

```
num1=50.960
num2=6.65E+07

set -- "$num1" "$num2"

e2f() {
  case $1 in
    *[eE]*) :;;
    *) set -- "$1e0"
  esac
  set -- "${1//+/}"
  set -- "${1//-/  _}"
  set -- "${1//[eE]/ 10 }"
  echo "$1^*"
}

eCmp() {
  test "$(dc -e "
15k[1p]sa$(e2f "$1") $(e2f "$2")r>a")" = 1
}

## and then...
if eCmp "$@"
then
  echo "$1 > $2"
else
  echo "$1 <= $2"
fi
```

**Output:**

```
50.960 <= 6.65E+07
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `bc` could perform all kinds of math operations. But it doesn't understand floats. Modern shell's printf understand floats but can not do math.

Let's join them:

```
$ num1=50.960
$ num2=6.65E+07
$ printf '%f < %f\n' "$num1" "$num2" | bc -l
1
```