# Are there awk versions that provide syntax for computing aggregations?

Tags: awk, statistics, dtrace

From time to time I find myself writing awk scripts that compute some simple statistics. For example computing a histogram, the average of a value, the standard deviation or even the variance ...

Doing that again and again with helper arrays/variables and for-loops in the `END` clause etc. feels a little bit tedious and error-prone.

In [Dtrace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTrace) there is a quite awesome syntax for such tasks which they call [aggregations](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/817-6223/chp-aggs/index.html). It is similar to the concept/API of [Accumulators in the Boost C++ library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/accumulators.html).

Thus my question: are there awk variants which provide similar concepts/syntax that allow for convenient and iterative computation of such statistics?

An imaginative example of such syntax:

```
$ someawk '{ @time[$1] = avg($2) }' measurements.log
prog1    150
prog2    200
....
```

(where the 1st column contains the program name, the 2nd the runtime of one measurement, `measurements.log` contains multiple measurements for each program and the aggregate function `avg` computes the average)

Comment: Maybe Perl might suit you better - it might be even worth the bigger resources it needs.

Comment: You may be interested in Num, which is uses AWK to calculate descriptive statisitcs such as count, mean, variance, etc. See http://www.numcommand.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Awk is designed for simple text processing. If you want more than that, there's a point where you need to ditch awk and use a more capable language.

[Perl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl) is the natural progression. It has most of the features of awk with a similar syntax, and is installed by default on most non-embedded unix systems. I'm not aware of any library for the kind of statistical analysis you describe, but there are [many libraries](http://www.cpan.org/) out there.

For statistical analysis, the language of choice is [R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_%28programming_language%29). It's weaker than awk on text processing, so unless your data is already in a format that R understands, you'll need to massage it first, possibly by piping awk into R. See [Is there a way to get the min, max, median, and average of a list of numbers in a single command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13731/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-min-max-median-and-average-of-a-list-of-numbers-in/13775#13775) for an example of using R that's similar to your example.