# How to get max, min, and mean from values in column 4

Tags: text-processing, numeric-data

I have data structured like this

```
X   43808504    G   1   ^]. <
X   43808505    C   3   .   4
X   43808506    T   8   .   ?
X   43808507    G   5   .   C
```

I want to get the max (8), min (1), and mean (4.25) from column 4 and write that to a file.

I've been wrestling with sorting and then cutting data away but that seems really inefficient.

Thanks for any help

Comment: You might want to take a look at `csvsql`, unless you require a solution without additional software.

Comment: Why not just use a for loop and do it yourself?  I don't know of a way to use `sort | cut` to get the mean anyway.

Comment: `awk '{print $4}'` but you could do the whole lot in `awk` pretty trivially

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/13731/117549

Answer (score 7):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'NR == 1 { min = $4; max = $4 }
{
    sum += $4
    if ($4 > max) {
        max = $4
    }
    if ($4 < min) {
        min = $4
    }
} END {
    print max
    print min
    print sum / NR
}' input
```

First we set the `min` and `max` variable as the value of the 4th column in line 1, later we will check each value in column 4 to see if it is less than the current value of `min` or more than the current value of `max`, if so set `min` to *that* value.

Then we create a `sum` variable with the sum of all values of column 4.  This will later be used to calculate the mean by dividing the sum by the total number of rows.

At the end we print the max, min, and mean.

Comment: Empty file gets a fatal divide-by-zero. print (NR ? sum / NR : "NaN")

Comment: @Paul_Pedant: Don't use it on an empty file.

Comment: I wouldn't. But users are a whole new thing. I like your initialising from NR==1. I use BEGIN and some arbitrary max and min, and it always looks clumsy.

Comment: If it's being run against an empty file it __should__ error IMO because something has been done wrong.

Answer (score 6):

With [Miller](https://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/)

```
$ mlr --nidx --repifs stats1 -a 'min,max,mean' -f 4 data
1 8 4.250000
```

You can redirect the output to a file in the usual way, by adding `> file`

With [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/)

```
$ datamash -W min 4 max 4 mean 4 < data
1   8   4.25
```