# Number formatting and rounding issue with awk

Tags: awk, command-line, text-formatting, numeric-data, mawk

I want to get the exact number when I try to find the average of a column of values.

For example, this is the column of input values:

```
1426044
1425486
1439480
1423677
1383676
1360088
1390745
1435123
1422970
1394461
1325896
1251248
1206005
1217057
1168298
1153022
1199310
1250162
1247917
1206836
```

When I use the following command:

```
... | awk '{ sum+=$1} END { print sum/NR}'
```

I get the following output: `1.31638e+06`. However, I want the exact number, which is `1316375.05` or even better, in this format  `1,316,375.05`

How can I do this with command line tools only?

**EDIT 1**

I found the following one-liner awk command which will get me the max, min and mean:

```
awk 'NR == 1 { max=$1; min=$1; sum=0 } { if ($1>max) max=$1; if ($1<min) min=$1; sum+=$1;} END {printf "Min: %d\tMax: %d\tAverage: %.2f\n", min, max, sum/NR}'
```

Why is it that NR must be initialized as 1? When I delete `NR == 1`, I get the wrong result.

**EDIT 2**

I found the following awk script from [Is there a way to get the min, max, median, and average of a list of numbers in a single command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13731/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-min-max-median-and-average-of-a-list-of-numbers-in/13779). It will get the sum, count, mean, median, max, and min values of a single column of numeric data, all in one go. It reads from stdin, and prints tab-separated columns of the output on a single line. I tweaked it a bit. I noticed that it does not need `NR == 1` unlike the awk command above (in my first edit). Can someone please explain why? I think it has to do with the fact that the numeric data has been sorted and placed into an array.

```
#!/bin/sh

sort -n | awk '

  $1 ~ /^(\-)?[0-9]*(\.[0-9]*)?$/ {
    a[c++] = $1;
    sum += $1;
  }
  END {
    ave = sum / c;
    if( (c % 2) == 1 ) {
      median = a[ int(c/2) ];
    } else {
      median = ( a[c/2] + a[c/2-1] ) / 2;
    }

    {printf "Sum: %d\tCount: %d\tAverage: %.2f\tMedian: %d\tMin: %d\tMax: %d\n", sum, c, ave, median, a[0], a[c-1]}
  }
'
```

Comment: You might try using a formatted print inside awk, e.g., `awk '{ sum+=$1} END { printf "%.2f\n", sum/NR}'`

Comment: Did you look at `printf` and its formatting options?

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!

Comment: Which bit is your question? Is it about the formatting of floating point numbers in the output, or about that thing with `NR`?

Comment: Please explain your codes

Comment: Like what does each part stand for.

Comment: I had two questions actually. The original question was about the formatting of floating point numbers in the output, then after it was answered, I had a follow up question about that thing with `NR`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
... | awk '{ sum+=$1} END { print sum/NR}'
```

By default, (GNU) awk prints numbers with up to 6 significant digits (plus the exponent part). This comes from the default value of [the `OFMT` variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/OFMT.html). It doesn't say that in the docs, but this only applies to non-integer valued numbers.

You could change `OFMT` to affect all `print` statements, or rather, just use `printf` here, so it also works if the average happens to be an integer. Something like `%.3f` would print the numbers with three digits after the decimal point.

```
...| awk '{ sum+=$1} END { printf "%.3f\n", sum/NR }'
```

See the docs for the meaning of the `f` and `g`, and the precision modifier (`.prec` in the second link):

- https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Control-Letters.html
- https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Format-Modifiers.html

```
awk 'NR == 1 { max=$1; min=$1; sum=0 } ...'
```

This doesn't initialize `NR`. Instead, it checks if `NR` is equal to one, i.e. we're on the first line. (`==` is comparison, `=` is assignment.) If so, initializes `max`, `min` and `sum`. Without that, `max` and `min` would start as zeroes. You could never have a negative maximum value, or a positive minimum value.

Comment: Note that it (or any POSIX awk implementation) only does that for non-integer numbers.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, figures, since otherwise even `1234567` wouldn't print accurately. Too bad the GNU docs don't seem to mention that. Thanks.

Comment: It's covered for `CONVFMT` though. See `info gawk 'Strings And Numbers'`. *As a special case, if a number is an integer, then the result of
converting it to a string is _always_ an integer, no matter what the
value of 'CONVFMT' may be*. It also says *Pre-POSIX 'awk' Used 'OFMT' for String Conversion*

Comment: Also note that there's some variation between `awk` implementations as to what is considered *integer*. See `echo 1e10 1e19 1e30 | awk '{print $1+0, $2+0, $3+0}'` in different awk implementations for instance.

Comment: @ikkachu Thanks for this explanation :) I still don't understand why when I use the awk command in Edit 1 without `NR == 1`, my output is : 'Min: 16214      Max: 16214      Average: 810.70' Do you mind walking me through what happens when `NR == 1` is omitted? And also why `NR == 1` is unnecessary in the script in Edit 2?

Comment: @rplee, if you remove the whole `NR == 1 { min=$1 ... }` block, then the min and max are implicitly initialized to zero, e.g. this shows `Min: 0`, even though the smallest number going in is 3: `seq 3 5 | awk ' { if ($1>max) max=$1; if ($1<min) min=$1; sum+=$1;} END {printf "Min: %d\tMax: %d\tAverage: %.2f\n", min, max, sum/NR}'`. If you just remove the condition `NR == 1`, but keep the following block `{ min=$1...}` , then `min`, `max` and `sum` are initialized again and again on _every_ line, and the output will show the last number as both the min and the max.

Comment: @rplee, that one-liner is short enough that you can walk it through line-by-line for some small input. The longer script use `sort` to to get the input numbers in order, so it doesn't need to keep track of the minimum and maximum values, it just looks at the first and last ones.

Comment: @iikachu Ah ok, I understand now. Thanks again.

Comment: @iikachu Is the `sum=0` even necessary? I ran the data through the awk command without the `sum=0` and it still gave me the same result.

Comment: @rplee, not strictly, but it's good style. The variables are autoinitialized as empty, and that acts like zero if you do arithmetic on it. But e.g. `print sum` would then just print an empty field, and not a zero. (`printf %f` forces it to be interpreted as a number)

Comment: @ilkkachu I see, that makes sense

Answer (score 6):

If using GNU `awk`, try this.  Adds the commas by making use of the `'` modifier.

```
$ awk '{sum+=$1}END{printf "%'\''.2f\n",sum/NR}' filename
1,316,375.05
$
```

If you've got `jq`, try this.

```
$ jq -s min,max,add/length filename
1153022
1439480
1316375.05
$
```

From [gnu.org : gawk Format Modifiers](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Format-Modifiers.html)

> A single quote or apostrophe character is a POSIX extension to ISO C. It indicates that the integer part of a floating-point value, or the entire part of an integer decimal value, should have a thousands-separator character in it. This only works in locales that support such characters. For example:

Comment: Hmm... when I try the awk command I get the following : `awk: run time error: improper conversion(number 1) in printf("%'.2f
")
        FILENAME="-" FNR=20 NR=20`

Comment: I am using mawk 1.3.3

Comment: @rplee - mawk 1.3.3 is well over 10 years old.  The `'` format modifier got introduced to mawk later.  See https://invisible-island.net/mawk/CHANGES.html#index-t20160927

Comment: Ah ok I installed the latest version of mawk (mawk 1.3.4 from 1/20/2020) and it worked